Does sectioning of sporangia of ferns kill the spores inside the sporangia?
In certain religions like Jainism, killing, or eating of seeds or unicellular microorganisms is banned. Does sectioning of sporangia kill all the spores? And by the way do the spores form a part of parent generation, or the offspring generation? Are the spores fully developed in the strobilus before dehiscence?

Welcome. In general, focused questions are best and a great way of doing this is by asking a single question per post (not 3 as here) and to add your research efforts so far; the second question seems readily answerable with an internet search. Further, if this Q pertains to adhering to religious values and norms, I would strongly recommend to ask this question on another stack and delete it here. Perhaps the site on vegetarianism and veganism can be of help.
